# How to disable Istio request log communication between services on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, istio-sidecar, google-anthos

I've just set up a GKE Cluster with Anthos service mesh enabled. I've noticed that every communication between services is registered on GCP's log ingestion system as I see them in Logs Dashboard. Something like this:

[image]

I couldn't find anywhere how to disable this log as it's not really usefull for me and I will also be charged for it's ingestion.

Comment: Are these logs ingested as DATA or AUDIT logs ? You don't get charged for Audit logs. You can check the Json Payload of the logs